# Which mathematical phenomena does the following video describe?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

I saw the following video at Paul Erdös group on Facebook:

https://www.facebook.com/ali.nesin.71/videos/10156407747615133/

[image]

What is the mathematics behind it?

Comment: Maybe you could add [this gif animation](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rsGXn.gif) to your post. (It is taken from [here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/34887/make-a-circle-illusion-animation).) It shows the same thing as the linked video, but the users do not have to click on the external link to see it.

Comment: This question seems related: [Equation of a curve of a point moving inside a circle](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/804069/equation-of-a-curve-of-a-point-moving-inside-a-circle). You can find there some relevant Wikipedia links, such as [Hypocycloid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypocycloid) and [Tusi couple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tusi_couple).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a special case of the hypocycloid, which is the curve described by a point of a circle rolling inside another (here with a double radius).

The center of the rolling circle describes a circle of the same radius. When this center turns by a quarter turn clockwise, the circle revolves by quarter turn, counter-clockwise.

Hence, a point on the circle follows the trajectory

$$x=\cos(t)+\cos(2t_0-t)=2\cos(t-t_0)\cos(t_0),\\y=\sin(t)+\sin(2t_0-t)=2\cos(t-t_0)\sin(t_0),$$

(where $2t_0$ is the initial angle of the point). This is a straight line of slope $\tan(t_0)$.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a polar form of the offset circle. A circle in the form

$$(x-1/2)^2+y^2=1/4$$
can be written also as
$$x^2+y^2=x$$
or
$$r=\cos\phi$$
in the polar form. Now, polar form just means that you specify the curve as a distance from the origin for each angle (distance along the lines in the video). Now interpret the position as a snapshot of oscillatory movement:
$$r=\cos(\phi-t)$$
where $t$ is time. This can now be interpreted as oscillations with the same amplitude for each angle, just with different phase delay.

So: a set of oscillating points with the same amplitude and phase delays proportional to their polar angles, always forms an offset circle that intersects the origin, with the circle orientation rotating in time.